# Trying to use the GTS to transfer pokemon from ORAS to X and Y, but it doesn't work

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

I got my Alpha Sapphire before I got my X, and since I am struggling a bit with the Elite 4 I figured it would be a good idea to send some of the pokemon that are strong, but not in my main team (competitive reasons, you know) over to X.
Unfortunately, I only have one 3DS and there's not enough space on my SD card to have ORAS, X and Pokebank. So I tried putting a Magikarp in the GTS on my X asking for Entei (which I had in ORAS and wanted to transfer), but when I searched for my Magikarp on ORAS, it didn't show up.

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong, and how to fix it?

Comment: You can filter the results by selecting the gender and/or level of the Magikarp. It is possible True what pinckerman says, there are a lot of Magikarps available on the GTS

Answer (score 1):

Search for it again, it must be there if nobody has accepted that (very unfair) trade.

It is actually possible to trade between ORAS and XY through GTS. If you don't see your Magikarp probably there are a lot of people offering that Pokemon at the moment.

Anyway if you want a faster way to trade between games you should find a friend with another console.

Comment: It might also help if you narrow down your search results, such as asking for an entei at a specific level, or asking for a magikarp with a specific gender and level. Using uncommon pokemon such as cacnea or carbink instead of magikarp would also help.

Comment: Good advice, Magikarp is a very common Pokemon on GTS